# How to cycle through all cells in a word table which is having split cells

Tags: vba, split, ms-word, iteration, cell

I have a 3 X 3 (say tableA) table in MS word.
The (2,2)th cell is a split cell(split into 2X2 table).
How can I cycle through all the cells in the tableA.

```
Dim strCellText As String
Dim uResp As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer

Dim itable As Table


For Each itable In ThisDocument.Tables

    uResp = ""

    For Row = 1 To itable.Rows.Count

        For Col = 1 To itable.Columns.Count

            strCellText = itable.Cell(Row, Col).Range.Text
            uResp = uResp & Trim(strCellText)                

        Next

    Next

    MsgBox uResp
Next
```

This program gives a compilation error:

```
Run time error 5914
The requested member of the collection does not exist
```

How can I iterate though cells of a tables which has split cells.

Comment: which line you have that error? generally, your code is correct which means it iterates through all cells as you require. So, your problem is somewhere else as I don't have any error working with your code.

Comment: @KazJaw Did you try with a table with split cells.

Comment: sorry, I missed that point, so I check it again...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should assume that each of the row has the maximum possible number of columns. In your situation, that would be four. To iterate through each cell, I propose to set `On Error Resume Next` before the first loop starts. Then inside your inner loop, try this code:

```
strCellText = itable.cell(Row, Col).Range.Text

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    uResp = uResp & Trim(strCellText)
    Debug.Print Row, Col, strCellText
Else
    Err.Clear
End If
```

Comment: +1 because it solves it for me too (thanks!); but this doesn't seem like the best option. Using error handling for normal program flow just seems 'ugh'. Is there really no better way?

Comment: @JaminGrey, what would you like to do in your situation? Cycle through all cells in table regardless they are splitted or merged?

Comment: The method you proposed works fine, but (perhaps from my C++ background), using error handling for normal and expected function flow just seems hacky. I'm not experienced in VBA, and I'm not criticizing your correct solution, merely commenting in surprise that VBA doesn't offer something cleaner (where, naturally, "cleaner" is biased by my personal opinions of past languages I've used). =) Chalk it up to newbie language shock.

Comment: The solution of mine was provided quite a long time ago. But answering question of cycling through each cell in first table in activedocument I would suggest this code: `For Each C In ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells` >> `'here do what you need for each cell` >> `Next C`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to go through all cells in all tables in a MS Word Document, even if the cells are merged, I got the results I wanted. Try this:

```
Sub CheckingInTheCell
Dim C as Cell
Dim tableCount, Ctr

tableCount = ActiveDocuments.tables.count

for Ctr = 1 to tableCount
   For each C in ActiveDocument.Tables(Ctr).Range.cells
       .....your validations or whatever you would like to do for the cell content
   next C
next Ctr

End Sub
```

Comment: sorry! the code was supposed to be line by line but all got together, I hope you can figure it out Lav

Answer (score 2):

I run into this situation when I am trying to extract data from (sometimes malformed) tables. This is how I handle it:

Check the number of columns

```
For each row in table.rows
  if row.cells.count < expectedRows
    'You know you are lacking rows
  else
    'Normal processing
  end if
Next
```

or Go through each cell if you want all the data anyway

```
For each row in table.rows
  For each cell in row.cells
    'Process individual cells
  Next
Next
```

None of those work if cells were merged vertically.