# Change table cells with background color yellow to font color red

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Word document that is generated from another program, and "highlighted" cells are created with a yellow cell background.

This behavior can't be changed. Also, the program that I need to copy the table into doesn't recognize background color.

I'm trying to change any cell with a yellow background to red text/font color.

```vb
Sub Highlight()
'
' Highlight Macro
' Applies color highlighting to the selection
'

Dim Tbl As Table
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables

    For j = 1 To Tbl.Columns.Count

        For i = 1 To Tbl.Rows.Count

            If Not (Tbl.Cell(i, j).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic) Then Tbl.Cell(i, j).Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed

        Next

    Next

Next

End Sub
```

This changes some cells (apparently the header row and first column) but skips all other cells and generates an error:

> The requested member of the collection does not exist.

It points to the line:

```
If Not (Tbl.Cell(i, j).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorAutomatic)
```

I think the problem is that the tables have some merged cells and the row/column index doesn't account for that. How do I account for merged cells?

Of note, all cells of interest are in rows that have no merged cells - meaning if I can either (1) ignore merged cells or (2) run a check to make sure a cell exists first, I think my problem will be fixed.

Comment: @TourEiffel I don't really understand your comment but I assume it has something to do with my post being cut off somehow! That is now fixed, thanks.

Comment: Do your tables have merged cells?  Try this approach to looping instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51972527/478884

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoiding problems with split/merged cells:

```
Sub Highlight()

    Dim Tbl As Table, C As Cell
    
    For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        For Each C In Tbl.Range.Cells
            If C.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor <> wdColorAutomatic Then
                C.Range.Font.ColorIndex = wdRed
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```